# flash html text tab

Tags: flash, textfield, htmltext

I am using a textField and assigning html text to it. There are some `<tab>` tags in the text but it is not working at all the places.

Is there any other tag, that we can use instead of

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just `\t` instead of HTML tag?